# Evaluating regexp within strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a simple requirement. I read a string from user( either *track or trAck*). I want  a logic using Regexp concept which will check this `user input` against a `regular expression` (within a string) :

```
 def test_regex
      string = "tr[Aa]ck"
      string1 = /#{Regexp.quote(string)}/ #tried something here
      user_input = "track" #or "trAck"
      if string1 == user_input
        puts "REGEX works"
      else
        puts "DIDN work"
      end
    end
 end
```

I know I have blindly written some code. Need the right direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `Regexp.quote`, or use [`Regexp::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-new). (If you use `Regexp.quote`, the resulting pattern will match `tr[Aa]ck` literally)

```
string1 = /#{string}/
# OR
# string1 = Regexp.new(string)
```

And use `=~` operator instead of `==` to match the regular expression against string.

```
if string1 =~ user_input
```

---

```
def test_regex
  string = "tr[Aa]ck"
  string1 = /#{string}/
  user_input = "track" #or "trAck"
  if string1 =~ user_input
    puts "REGEX works"
  else
    puts "DIDN work"
  end
end
```

Comment: Works like Charm!! will accept your answer in 10 minutes :) Thanks a lot!!

Comment: How can we convert a regex back to string?? Actually I need to combine my regex within a string.

Comment: @akshatha, You can use [`Regexp#source`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-i-source) to get back the string.